# Checkbox click not working from within unordered list item

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-lists, bind, expandable

I am unable to 'check' an input checkbox that is embedded in an expandable UL.  I know the reason has something to do with click binding but I just can't figure it out.

The UL is dynamic so I add new li's and UL's. The lowest level UL contains lis that should be selectable.  However when I try to click on them it just highlights the label and the checkbox never becomes checked.

Here's the HTML:

```
<li id="JeffID4" class="collapsed expanded">
    Assessment
    <ul class="inputs-list" style="display: block;">
        <li id="apple">
           <label class="checkbox inline">
             <input type="checkbox">
             ATGM
           </label>
        </li>
        <li id="apple">
           <label class="checkbox inline">
             <input type="checkbox">
             FMS
           </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Here's the javascript/jquery:

```
function prepareList() {
  $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')    
    .click( function(event) {
        //If line item is expandable but has no line items then call the service to retrieve data
      if($(event.target).hasClass('collapsed') && $(event.target).find('li').length==0){
         $(event.target).children('ul').append("Add New LI's")
         $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)').addClass('collapsed');
         $('#expList').find('ul').addClass('inputslist');                     $(event.target).find('li:has(input)').unbind();               
         $(event.target).children('ul').hide();
        }

        //Toggle the lists if they show or not
        $(event.target).toggleClass('expanded');
        $(event.target).children('ul').slideToggle('medium');
        return false;
    })
    .addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').children('ul').hide(); 
};


    $(document).ready( function() {
       prepareList()
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Well click events bubble up through the DOM, and `return false;` from a click handler stops the default behaviour for the click, so... why are you returning false? You could add `if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==="input") return;` (without `false`) to the beginning of your click handler to stop further processing when an input (including checkboxes) is clicked. Or `if ($(event.target).is("input")) return;` if you think my first suggestion didn't have enough jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `false` from the `li` `click` event so the event never gets to the checkbox. Just remove the line `return false;` from the event handler and the checkbox will work normally. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhusaini/udc8f/).

Comment: I see!  Can't believe I missed that.  The only problem is if I remove the return false, the click events will bubble up resulting in multiple 'toggles' but I was able to use event.stoppropogation() instead and now everything is working.  Thanks!

Comment: Right, `return false;` has the combined effect of calling `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` together. Since you only want the former, it makes sense to call it explicitly.