# Checkboxes/radiobuttons unresponsive in expandable list form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, expandable

Edit to answer: OK, so it seems this problem has come up before. The key seems to be in the `return false;` statement in the js prepareList function. I commented it out and now the code works fine. For more information and a more complete answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120231/checkbox-click-not-working-from-within-unordered-list-item?rq=1) is the previous version of the question.

EDIT: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHk2r/) that reproduces the error.

I'm trying to make a form using the expandable list code found [here](http://jasalguero.com/ledld/development/web/expandable-list/), and my checkboxes and radio buttons are either unresponsive or glitchy. They both know they're being pressed, they change to the depressed image when I click on them, but they don't update their value. For radio buttons, I can click one and it works, but then the others in that group become unresponsive. I have a dummy php page to just print out the results of the form, but it doesn't appear to be receiving any data. NOTE: This is my first website project, there may be something completely obvious that I'm just missing.
Here's a sample of the HTML:

```
<div id="listContainer">
        <div class="listControl">
            <a id="expandList">Expand All</a>
            <a id="collapseList">Collapse All</a>
        </div>
        <form id="ColForm" action="Table.php" method="post"> <!--Organized list of collumns and filter options-->
        <ul id="expList">
        <li>Section heading
            <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="ColSelect" value="Name" form="ColForm"> <!--If checked, collumn will be included in final table--> Name
                <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" form="ColForm"><br> <!--filter parameter input-->
                </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="ColSelect" value="RA,Dec" form="ColForm">Another collumn
                <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="PoSearch" value="Range" form="ColForm">Radio button to select form type for this section<br>
                    <i>I have an option here
                    <input type="radio" name="Degs" value="Dec" form="ColForm">Option 1 
                    <input type="radio" name="Degs" value="Hex" form="ColForm">Option 2</i><br>
                    Text input 1<br>
                    <input type="text" name="RA" form="ColForm">deg<br>
                    Text input 2<br>
                    <input type="text" name="Dec" form="ColForm">deg<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="PoSearch" value="Area" form="ColForm">Second form option<br>
                    <i>Text input A</i><br>
                    <input type="text" name="Area" form="ColForm"><br>
                </li>
                </ul>    
            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" form="ColForm">
    </form>
</div>
```

And here's the javascript for the list function:

```
/**************************************************************/
/* Prepares the cv to be dynamically expandable/collapsible   */
/**************************************************************/
function prepareList() {
    $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
    .click( function(event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        return false;
    })
    .addClass('collapsed')
    .children('ul').hide();

    //Create the button functionality
    $('#expandList')
    .unbind('click')
    .click( function() {
        $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
    })
    $('#collapseList')
    .unbind('click')
    .click( function() {
        $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
    }) 
};

$(document).ready( function() {
    prepareList()
});
```

And the relevant CSS:
    #listContainer{
      margin-top:15px;
    }

```
#expList ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#expList p {
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}
#expList p:hover {
    background-color:#121212;
}
#expList li {
    line-height:140%;
    text-indent:0px;
    background-position: 1px 8px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Collapsed state for list element */
#expList .collapsed {
    background-image: url(../img/collapsed.png);
}
/* Expanded state for list element
/* NOTE: This class must be located UNDER the collapsed one */
#expList .expanded {
    background-image: url(../img/expanded.png);
}
#expList {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I've added your code to a fiddle, but am unable to re-create your problem (as I understand it).

Comment: @badAdviceGuy Weird, I've tried it on Chrome and Safari after uploading it, and the checkboxes just refuse to toggle.

Comment: I saw on another question about a similar issue that they somehow removed the `return false` in the JS and used `event.stopPropagation()` instead, but I don't know how to implement that. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120231/checkbox-click-not-working-from-within-unordered-list-item?rq=1) a link to that discussion.

Comment: I'm seeing the issue in the fiddle you've added, I'll take a look and see if I can figure anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is with `event.preventDefault()` in your code. It's keeping the checkboxes / radio buttons from performing their default behavior. Removing that entry will allow the input tags to function normally. But they will no longer trigger the expand and collapse functionality you're looking for.

You'll need to modify your JS to also listen for the click on the checkboxes. Here are some similar situations that may help you:

[making on-click events work with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123/how-do-i-make-a-checkbox-toggle-from-clicking-on-the-text-label-as-well)

[clicking on a div to check / uncheck a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584239/click-on-a-div-to-toggle-a-checkbox-inside-of-it-using-javascript)

Comment: I don't see `event.preventDefault` in the code anywhere, but the code seems to be working fine now. I have buttons (+ and - icons) that expand and collapse the list, and the checkboxes seem to be behaving like they should now that I've taken out `return false`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. When you add `return false;` in jQuery it acts like a `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopProppagation()`

Comment: So can I just replace the `return false` with `event.stopPropagation()`?